# Passing month to pl/sql function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, date-arithmetic

I want to Write a function that returns the Products brought in a given month.

I tried this

```
 create or replace 
 function myfun(mymonth date) 
    return date
 is  
    cursor cur 
    is 
       select * 
         from products 
        where purchase_date=mymonth;
 begin
    for i in cur
    loop
       dbms_output.put_line(i.product_id || ', ' || 
                            i.description || ', ' || 
                            i.product_name || ', ' || 
                            i.quantity || ', ' || 
                            i.price || ', ' || 
                            i.purchase_date);
    end loop;
    return 1;
 end;
```

this giving me error.
how can i pass month to pl/sql function and retrieve the data.

Comment: please provide us error message

Comment: What is yout table structure? What are you passing in? Your function says it returns a DATE but you are trying to return 1 which is a number. There's a lot wrong with what you have posted here and you need to supply more info for us to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a date ('01-MAY-2003') and use date functions to make it work:

```
create or replace 
 function myfun(mymonth date) 
    return date
 is  
    cursor cur 
    is 
       select * 
         from products 
        where purchase_date >= TRUNC(mymonth, 'MM')
          and purchase_date < ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC(mymonth,'MM') , 1 );
```

Using `TRUNC(x, 'MM')` on the input month means you can pass in *any* date at teh query will run from the first day of the month.

Alternatively, you could use the `LAST_DAY()` function which returns the start of the last day of the input month. You'd have to watch out for time values, since the Oracle DATE datatype can include both date and time.

Comment: giving me error. `8/30           PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
6/8            PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/1           PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:`

Comment: Typo in the sample code. The "=" sign in the last line should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you need is only to compare the month from the purchase_date column with the month on the param of the function...

I would do it this way

```
cursor cur 
is 
   select * 
     from products 
    where TO_CHAR(purchase_date,'MM') >= TO_CHAR(mymonth, 'MM')
```

If you want to include also the year, you could use 'RRRRMM' as a param of TO_CHAR, instead of 'MM'